# Change QML font.pointSize in C++

Tags: c++, qt, font-size, qml

I have managed to change the "color" property of QML text with C++ using this:

```
theText->setProperty("color", "red");
```

but if I try

```
theText->setProperty("font.pointSize", 20);
```

then nothing happens(it's not that size), I've tried this with other things that include a "." but none seem to work, I think the "." may be part of the problem. I'd really appreciate if someone could help me change the QML font size using C++.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look for actual property name. And as far as i know there is no sub-properties in QObjects... So you need something like this:

```
QFont f = theText->property("font").value<QFont>();
f.setPointSize(20);
theText->setProperty("font",f);
```